# Wordpress : How to "group" (categorize) the Pages together?

Tags: wordpress, grouping, categories, taxonomy, custom-fields

I have a lot of `Pages` which can be (need to be) grouped under a number of different Categories. ** Then the more important thing is, i need to control those pages (of different groups) programatically via `functions.php`.

Lets say, i would have:

- Page A (Categorized as: `Fruits`)
- Page B (Categorized as: `Vehicles`)
- Page C (Categorized as: `Vehicles`)
- Page D (Categorized as: `Fruits`)
- Page E (Categorized as: `Technology`)

Then from `functions.php`, there would be some logics, like:

- If Page is under `Fruits` Category, then `echo "This is related to Fruits.";`.
- If Page is under `Vehicles` Category, then `echo "This is related to Vehicles.";`.
- If Page is under `Technology` Category, then `echo "This is related to Technologies.";`.

I dont know this is about Taxonomy or Tagging or Custom Field or something. But:

- **What is the ideal way to do it please? *(Especially to be able to control from backend coding.)***

Comment: use a taxonomy or tag if you intend to group in post archives, just use post meta if its for display only. Tons of examples out there for all three options if you google it.

Comment: Did you mean "Posts"?

Comment: im not sure what your talking about? post_meta is a table in your db.